# How to get the content of website in phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have to design a android,ios application for my website.I searched and find out that phonegap can be good one for that.Please provide me info that how to get the content of website in phonegap?On the first page i have buttons like home,contact etc.On click of home button,the home page from website should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap is set of libraries like jQuery.
You normally write html pages and include javascript files from phonegap.

Check out phonegap example project.

Answer (score 0):

Look, what you are talking about is `.html`,`.css`,`.js` files that you can easily get after saving any web page from your web-browser.

> Rest you can use in the `www` folder of your `phonegap` project. And I
>   would rather suggest you to go for `webview` present in the native
>   android that is nothing but actually would provide you the same
>   functionality that you have been looking for.

**---Edit---**

Now as you have said that you want the home page buttons like about us etc. that would be copied via web browser and would be there for you as far as the html code is concerned but if you want it to look well on a small mobile device that you should create a responsive designed html and you should read some good articles about responsive web design. That would actually change your way of thinking about creating applications via `html` within mobile devices.